# How can I disable validation for an input that is disable in Angular?

Tags: angular

I have a form and in it some inputs. The inputs have css class: pointer-events: none, which disables the ability to edit the input (disable). I have the form validation done, unfortunately the button to save, does not unlock for me. Does this validation still work underneath despite the disable class being set? How could I achieve something like this, so that I only have to fill in the inputs that are not disable, and on this basis I can click on my button?

```
<input 
   formControlName="numbers" [ngClass]="{'disabled-style': control.get('isTrue').value" 
   [required]='control.get('isTrue').value'/>
<button (click)="save()">Save status</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

If an input field is disabled using CSS (`pointer-events: none` in this case), it will still be considered as part of the form, but it won't be editable by the user. However, disabled fields are typically not included in form submission, so if you're relying solely on HTML form submission behavior, the disabled fields won't be included.

If you're using Angular's reactive forms, Angular will still consider disabled fields for validation purposes, regardless of their disabled status. Therefore, if you're using Angular's form validation mechanisms, disabled fields will still be validated.

In your case, it seems like you want to enable the "Save" button only if certain conditions are met, including whether the input field is not disabled. One way to achieve this is to dynamically enable/disable the button based on the validity of the form and the state of the input fields.

Here's an example of how you might do this in your Angular component:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
  <input formControlName="numbers" [ngClass]="{'disabled-style': control.get('isTrue').value}" [required]="!control.get('isTrue').value" />
  <button (click)="save()" [disabled]="!myForm.valid || control.get('isTrue').value">Save status</button>
</form>
```

And in your component class:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-your-component',
  templateUrl: './your-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./your-component.component.css']
})
export class YourComponent implements OnInit {
  myForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      numbers: ['', Validators.required],
      isTrue: [false] // Assuming this is a boolean control indicating whether the input should be enabled/disabled
    });

    // Subscribe to changes in the isTrue control to dynamically update validation
    this.myForm.get('isTrue').valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
      if (value) {
        this.myForm.get('numbers').clearValidators();
      } else {
        this.myForm.get('numbers').setValidators(Validators.required);
      }
      this.myForm.get('numbers').updateValueAndValidity();
    });
  }

  get control() {
    return this.myForm.controls;
  }

  save() {
    // Your save logic here
  }
}
```

In this example:

- The "Save" button is disabled if the form is invalid
  (`!myForm.valid`) or if the `isTrue` control is set to `true`.
- The validation of the `numbers` field is dynamically updated based on
  the value of the `isTrue` control. If `isTrue` is `true`, the
  validation is cleared, allowing the field to be considered valid even
  though it's disabled.

With this setup, the button will only be enabled if the form is valid and the conditions for enabling/disabling the input field are met.

Comment: a FormControl "disabled" is not invalid (the [status](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControlStatus) of a form control can be VALID, INVALID, PENDING **or** DISABLED. So, if our formControl is disabled, it's not invalid and out FromGroup is not invalid. So you **should** disable the formControl instead clear validators.

Comment: This answer looks AI generated